# How to send a request to remote server from kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have a problem. My problem is trying to access a remote server by query from kibana. I accessed my private host address from Elasticsearch and created an index here and transferred some data. I want to see this index and data from kibana, but I was able to access kibana from localhost:5624. Previously, I could not access the kibana.yml file by changing the following information:

```
my kibana.yml file:
server.port: xxxx
server.host: "xx.xx.xxx.xxx"
server.name: "my_server_name"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx"]
elasticsearch.username: "my_user_name"
elasticsearch.password: "my_password"
```

Maybe this problem can be solved by sending request from kibana to remote server but when i run this queries it also gave error.

```
GET https://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/my_index_name/_search
{
   "query": {
       "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

or

```
GET xx.xx.xxx.xxx/my_index_name/_search
{
   "query": {
       "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

or

```
GET xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/my_index_name/_count?pretty
```

Error:

```
#! [types removal] Specifying types in search requests is deprecated.
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [xx.xx.xxx.xxx]",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id" : "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "xx.xx.xxx.xxx"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index [xx.xx.xxx.xxx]",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "xx.xx.xxx.xxx"
  },
  "status" : 404
}
```

I will be happy so much if you help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: What error do you exactly get? Please add it to your question.

Comment: I edited it again, now I would be very happy if you could help me, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as the error message states: the index you're sending the search request against does not exist. Make sure to create an index before you search it.

Also: No index means no data. Before searching, complete the following steps:

1.) Create index

2.) Ingest documents into that index

3.) Search

If you are using Logstash with an Elasticsearch output, Logstash creates the configured index for you **but not until Logstash sends data to Elasticsearch.**

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will take what you said into consideration, but while creating the conf file, I specified the name of the index and transferred the data into this index. I am sure of that. Now I can't view the data. Maybe there is another problem that I don't fully understand.